# read 16 bit or 32 bit images in python

Tags: python, image

How can I read in 16 bit or 32 bit images by python and get the correct image values as an array?

I tried to read in SRTM (Shuttle Radar Topography Mission) using PIL + Numpy, and GDAL + Numpy etc. I just need a small piece, so I use ArcGIS to get the extents I need as a tif file.

However, though the above testing, the values in the array are incorrect. 
For example, I used a SRTM in CA whose elevation range is from 136 to 737, but when I use numpy to get the maximum and minimum values, the array value range is from -3.40 to 737, and it appears lots of negative values. 
what can I do? Do I make some mistakes?

The code I used is as following using ipython:

```
import Image
import numpy as num
im=Image.open('srtm.tif')
imarray=num.array(im)
imarray
array([[ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
   [ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
   [ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
   ...,
   [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]], dtype=float32)
import gdal
tif = gdal.Open('srtm.tif')
arr = tif.ReadAsArray()
arr
array([[ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
     -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38],
   [ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
      6.11000000e+02,   6.17000000e+02,   6.17000000e+02],
   [ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,   4.00000000e+02, ...,
      6.11000000e+02,   6.17000000e+02,   6.17000000e+02],
   ...,
   [  1.50000000e+02,   1.50000000e+02,   1.48000000e+02, ...,
      1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02],
   [  1.49000000e+02,   1.49000000e+02,   1.48000000e+02, ...,
      1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02],
   [  1.49000000e+02,   1.49000000e+02,   1.48000000e+02, ...,
      1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02,   1.73000000e+02]], dtype=float32)

num.max(arr)
737.0
num.min(arr)
-3.4028235e+38
```

Comment: Can you post your code and results?

Comment: What format are the files you are working with?  A quick look at the SRTM website shows me it's offered in a number of formats.

Comment: I think the tif file does not have a GDAL_NODATA tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that these values are actually right. Many forms of scientific images use specific values that are either extremely high or extremely low to represent null or saturated pixels. My suggestion would be not include those pixels in any calculations or to set them to zero like: `arr[arr < 0] = 0`.

Comment: I tried to set negative values as zero, and found some pixels on the right side are zero. That is to say, I just read in parts of image. Why does this situation happen?